Symlinks with data inside directory
I'm using this symlinks
ln -s "$REPO_DIR/src/packages/my-project/out" "$OUTPUT_PATH"
Currently, my OUTPUT_PATH only has only 1 folder out
How can I make my OUTPUT_PATH has all the things inside folder out with symlinks (not copy because I don't want to take time loop through out folder)
I'm trying this but not sure does it solve the problem, or any other way that run fast ?
ln -s "$REPO_DIR/src/packages/my-project/out/"* "$OUTPUT_PATH"

ln -s "$REPO_DIR/src/packages/my-project/out/"* "$OUTPUT_PATH" should work (as long as $OUTPUT_PATH is a directory and $REPO_DIR and $OUTPUT_PATH don't start with - as you forgot the -- to delimit ln options). Have you tried it?

Your

ln -s "$REPO_DIR/src/packages/my-project/out/"* "$OUTPUT_PATH"


As long as $OUTPUT_PATH is a directory, should make one symlink for each of the non-hidden entries of the $REPO_DIR/src/packages/my-project/out directory.
Note that if $REPO_DIR is a relative path, then that will likely not work properly as upon resolution, the link targets will be interpreted as relative to $OUTPUT_PATH not to your current working directory.
Using the -r/--relative option of GNU ln can help in that case as it computes the right relative path for the target of the link:
ln -rs -- "$REPO_DIR/src/packages/my-project/out/"* "$OUTPUT_PATH"

(also note the -- to avoid problems if $REPO_DIR or $OUTPUT_PATH starts with -).
If there is a very large number of entries in the source directory, then the command may reach the system's limit on the size of a command line and fail.
(cd -P -- "$REPO_DIR/src/packages/my-project/out" &&
 ln -sr -- * "$OUTPUT_PATH")

(assuming $OUTPUT_PATH is an absolute path) would make the command shorter reducing the risk of that limit being reached, or you could use:
xargs -r0a <(printf '%s\0' "$REPO_DIR/src/packages/my-project/out"/*
  ) ln -srt "$OUTPUT_PATH" --

Where xargs will break down the list in smaller chunks that execve() can swallow OK.
